# Heroku seems to build client but I see no dist folder

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, mean-stack

When pushing my angular/node app to heroku it seems to build successfully when I look at the logs. But I can see no dist folder being created in the angular side.

I built the angular client locally to make sure there were no errors in the code.

I have changed the build script from -
"postinstall": "ng build --prod"

which was throwing "path to environment.prod.ts could not be found" error to

"heroku-postbuild": "ng build --configuration=production"

which doest throw errors but doesn't continue to create the dist folder. So I am stuck right a bit.

angular package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --configuration=production"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@vguleaev/angular-material-autocomplete": "0.0.10",
    "@w11k/ngx-componentdestroyed": "^4.1.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-observable-store": "^1.0.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.0.0",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  }
}
```

node package.json

```
{
  "name": "spotify-alias",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.0.0",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "cookie-session": "^1.3.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.14",
    "node-fetch": "^2.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-spotify": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "server": "nodemon --exec babel-node app.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false && npm install --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

app.js - node

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('/client/dist/index.html'));

    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "dist", "index.html"));
    });
}
```

I would like everything to build and the dist folder to be created. This is my first node app so please bear with me, there might be things that look completely off.

Like I am not 100% sure about the app.js code that resolves the path. I do know that /client is where the angular stuff is from root.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: did you find any solution. I am stuck in similar position

Comment: @ApurvaPathak take a look at my config, I did eventually get it working. Watch the path to your client dist folder and get the heroku cmds correct and you should be ok. `https://github.com/godhar/spotify-alias/blob/master/server/package.json`

Comment: Yeah I figured it out too. Issue was in package.json file. Value to start:heroku was wrong. thanks by the way

Comment: @ApurvaPathak glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a build script. I see that you're using Babel. Thus, you need to tell Babel to run a build for you; which ultimately provides the dist folder (could be any name though).

```
"build": "babel src --out-dir dist --copy-files",
```

Comment: Babel has nothing to fo with the angular client. Neither is there a build step for node. @parkerthegeniuschild

Answer (score 0):

Do follow the blog to deploy angular apps on heroku

https://medium.com/@hellotunmbi/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147

Comment: That is the tutorial I have followed. You can see the steps I took map the steps in the tutorial.